# Проверить скрыт ли элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animation

Хочу написать менюшку на jQuery. 
Проблема в том что не смог проверить скрыт элемент или нет , знаю про свойства hide(),show(), toggle()  но как с ними проверить?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#toggle').click(function() {
          $('#sub_menu').toggle();
          if ( //#sub_menu не скрыт)
            {
              alert('sub menu opened')
            } else {
              alert('sub menu closed')
            }
          })
      });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 90px;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: #aaaaaa;
  position: relative;
}
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  top: 35px;
}
ul li ul>li {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <ul>
    <li id='toggle'>Home
      <ul id='sub_menu'>
        <li>subItem1</li>
        <li>subItem2</li>
        <li>subItem3</li>
        <li>subItem4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>About</li>

    <li>Contact</li>

    <li>Log out</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте проверить `.is(':visible')`

Т.е. в Вашем случае что-то типа такого:

```
  if ($('#sub_menu').is(':visible'))
    {
      alert('sub menu opened')
    } else {
      alert('sub menu closed')
    }
  })
```

Comment: спасибо работает :) но _:visible_ это псевдокласс CSS3 и  с ним могут быть проблемы в старых браузерах ?

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) написано, что `hide()` - эквивалент такой записи: `.css( "display", "none" )`.

Соответственно проверить, скрыт ли элемент можно, например, так:

```
if ($(elem).css('display') == 'none') {
    console.log('скрыт');
} else {
    console.log('виден');
}
```

Либо же, используя Vanilla JS:

```
if (elem.style.display == 'none') {
    console.log('скрыт');
} else {
    console.log('виден');
}
```